# Removing an interaction term after checking for homogeneity of regression slopes

Tags: generalized-linear-model, ancova, regression-coefficients

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interpreting main effect and interaction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19891/interpreting-main-effect-and-interaction)

In a GLM, I had one categorical predictor and one covariate. To ensure the covariate was consistent across levels of my predictor I included an interaction term. This was non significant. Am I then justified in removing it from the model? My categorical predictor is non significant when it is included, but significant when it is removed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does any underlying theory predict the interaction ought to be there?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I included it only to test the assumption of homogeneity of regression slopes.

Comment: Then I'm sure your question is a duplicate of several closely related questions about regression, significance, and covariates, including (but not limited to) http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19891 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22680. For more, [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2B[regression]+%2Bsignificance+%2Binteraction).